# Getting Count of leading space and &nbsp;

Tags: javascript, regex

I want count of leading(beaning of stance) space and `&nbsp;` in JavaScript. 
 I tried below code but it doesn't work:

```
<script>

var clone = '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;test my &nbsp; &nbsp;string';
matches = clone.match(/\&nbsp;/gm);
alert(matches.length);
</script>
```

it should output/give 3 in result but it's giving 5. Please guide me.

Comment: But in your clone string variable you have 5 times &nbsp;. Why you expect 3 instead 5 ?

Comment: I want only leading means before starting the stance.

Comment: Because he wants the leading ones only.

Comment: My fault, sorry

Comment: Requirements are not clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try this regex, I have got the solution with use of match two times here.

```js
var clone = '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;test my &nbsp; &nbsp;string';
matches  =  clone.match(/^(\&nbsp;)*/)[0].match(/&nbsp;/gm);
alert(matches.length);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I understand that you want to get the leading spaces at the beginning of the string. You can modigy the match like so:

```
matches = clone.match(/^[\&nbsp;]*\&nbsp;/gm);
```

Comment: giving result 1

Comment: That is because there is one set of &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp before the first word. Wasn't this what you wanted?

Comment: I need count 3 if  &nbsp; 3 times if 4 times count should be 4